# How to resolve "error: ';' expected" error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to follow a tutorial video on Youtube. When I try to look at it in the Emulator as he does in his video the following error appears.

> Error:(22, 48) error: ';' expected
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I have done a quick web search and people suggest to check the JDK file location. I have done this which hasn't helped. This is my JDK location.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

This is the small piece of code I copied from the tutorial.

```
package shmaves.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //layout
    RelativeLayout shmavesLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    shmavesLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    //Button
    Button redButton = new Button (this);
    redButton.setText ("click me");
    redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)


    //Add widget to layout (button is now a child of layout
    shmavesLayout.addView(redButton);

    //Set this activities content/display to this view
    setContentView(shmavesLayout);

}
}
```

Can anyone shed some light or see where I have gone wrong? I am new to all this so please be thorough with any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The line 22 miss a ";":

```
redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

If you are new on Android studio, you may not seeing line number in your IDE, you need to change this configuration:

Go to File > Settings. In the dialog, select 'Editor', then the
    sub-option for 'General', and then the sub-option for 'Appearance'.
    Select 'Show line numbers' as shown below. Click Ok.

Comment: The ";" worked thanks. He covered the line numbers earlier in his tutorial, I just didn't copy them. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

**Every single statement in Java requires a `;` at the end to denote its end.**

The error even tells you that:

> ';' expected

You just have to find where you missed a semi-colon. Try to find it yourself!

Answer:

> `redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)`

Comment: This worked. Thankyou! I wasn't aware that is what it was saying.

Answer (score 1):

As the error messages says:

> Error:(22, 48) error: ';' expected

you forgot the character ';' behind redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)

Comment: This worked, thanks heaps! I will pay more attention!